# How to save in a database more than one product in a simulation of a online shopping process in Camunda?

Tags: process, camunda, bpmn, camunda-modeler

[BPMN image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTDJUvAaNTLm5qNqk7e3yANwCE2NOMBG/view?usp=drive_link)

Hi, we tried to map a process of an online shopping business with Camunda Modeler. After mapping it, we tried to implement the simulation by adding forms in JSON. In the image, you can see the first part of the process. You can see the start event followed by a gateway and then a series of tasks where the client selects the product, picks a size and adds the product to the cart. After that, we ask the client if he wants another product or if he wants to continue with the payment. Here is where the problem resides, because if the client chooses to add a new product, the previous product doesn't remain saved in "IdOrdine" as a variable but it is replaced by the new one.

[Variables simulation 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kL-drVFQtfPO7IpdMYIeDRQZSIQlxSrk/view?usp=drive_link) [Variables simulation 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqjljfsB8x2DBmmayqS6YY4NAmpKOQa-/view?usp=drive_link) [Variables simulation 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ndamymmn6for-Sow49WFfXcfCNSk-WIt/view?usp=drive_link)

Thanks for the help

We didn't try anything specific...we are new to the software

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with multiple products, you will need some collection variable that stores all products. A single variable will naturally be overwritten by the next loop.